# Browser is getting closed in a second in selenium with Python program

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Drivers\Chrome")
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username").send_keys("Admin")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys("admin123")
driver.close()
```

**Error I am getting:**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Drivers\Chrome")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\FirstDemo.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Drivers\Chrome")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-``packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 106, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 117, in assert_process_still_running
    return_code = self.process.poll()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
```

Need solution to problem to run the program without error.

Answer (score 0):

The path you have provided in the code C:\Users\Drivers\Chrome looks incomplete. Make sure you have provided the complete path of the "chromedriver" executable file. Also is better to check if you have downloaded the correct version of chromedriver that is compatible with the version of Chrome installed on your system.
Update the selenium package to the latest version using pip. (pip install --upgrade selenium)